# C++ testing classes with Catch

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, clion

I decided to make a small project which I will cover with tests as much as I can. I'm using CLion (which uses CMake) and Catch library for testing.

The problem is that I'm getting `undefined reference to TestClass::add` method while I run test class.

Here is my setup (it's a dummy one since I wanted to make sure if everything works):

**TestClass.h**

```
#ifndef LLL_TESTCLASS_H
#define LLL_TESTCLASS_H

class TestClass {
public:
    int add(int a, int b);
};

#endif //LLL_TESTCLASS_H
```

**TestClass.cpp**

```
#include "TestClass.h"
int TestClass::add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

**test.cpp -- file with tests**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "../src/TestClass.h"

TEST_CASE("addition") {
    TestClass testClass;
    REQUIRE(testClass.add(2,3) == 5);
    REQUIRE(testClass.add(-1, 1) == 0);
    REQUIRE(testClass.add(2, 4) == 1);
}
```

**CMakeLIsts.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(LLL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(LIB_DIR "lib")
include_directories(${LIB_DIR}/Catch)
include_directories(${LIB_DIR}/Eigen)

set(SRC_DIR src)
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp src/TestClass.h src/TestClass.cpp)
add_executable(LLL ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(TEST_DIR test)
set(TEST_FILES ${TEST_DIR}/test.cpp)
add_executable(LLL_TEST ${TEST_FILES})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify the TestClass.{.h, .cpp} to be compiled in `LLL_TEST` executable target:

```
set(TEST_FILES src/TestClass.h src/TestClass.cpp ${TEST_DIR}/test.cpp)
```

Or better move it in some shared library and just link to it.

The problem is because your project produces 2 executables: `LLL` and `LLL_TEST` targets. Each of them have a object files and a references. In `LLL` target these references to `TestClass` are satistifed because they are compiled in the `LLL` target so the `ld` can simply link them. But in case of `LLL_TEST` target compiler can't find these symbols because they are not specified in this target - that's why compiler says that he can't resolve a reference.

Comment: thank, that works...but can you explain me this part: "Or better move it in some shared library and just link to it"? I am new to whole c++ and build systems stuff and used Java and Python libraries that are fairly easy to install and use, so I am kinda lost :/

Comment: @SvenVidak if it helped you - accept it as an answer so that other people with this trouble may know the solution. About a libraries - it needs very-very huge amount of text, also it needs a lot of time to understand. I'd suggest you to read a good book about `C` and `C++`. But the libraries, in my opinion, are goodly explained only in some unix/linux books.

Comment: I have to wait 2 more minutes to be able to acccept the answer. About shared libs - I have some knowledge about them, but as far as I know I would have to recreate them every time I want to test something and that would be really tiresome if I want to do something like TDD. Am I right?

Comment: If you do `TDD` - yes. Of course you should think about your project's architecture and optimize it.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that yes, you would need to recreate the lib everytime you change something and want to test it, but if you set it up as in tamas.kenez's answer, the process is **not** tiresome at all, it is just as a regular rebuild, which you have to do anyway just as in java.

Answer (score 6):

Your question has already been answered by Polevoy and he's also correct about factorizing out your class to a library.

I'd just like to show how the library version would look like. You can decide whether it's really so complicated you need to read books or if it has any overhead for doing TDD.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(LLL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # adds -std=c++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(LIB_DIR "lib")
include_directories(${LIB_DIR}/Catch)
include_directories(${LIB_DIR}/Eigen)

add_library(LLL_LIB src/TestClass.h src/TestClass.cpp)

add_executable(LLL src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(LLL LLL_LIB)

add_executable(LLL_TEST test/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(LLL_TEST LLL_LIB)
```

This script creates the static library `LLL_LIB` which is linked into both executables. You can build a shared one instead if you like:

```
add_library(LLL_LIB SHARED src/TestClass.h src/TestClass.cpp)
```

but static is just fine here.